# geany cannot run file built by g++ on kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, c++, g++, geany

I used geany and g++ on Ubuntu, they were working just fine.

But now I just installed Kubuntu, and geany just doesn't work as usual. Geany builds and compiles with g++, but it cannot run the file. What I see is a blank console screen every time I ran a cxx file.

Geany commands:

```
compile : g++ -Wall -c "%f"
build : g++ -Wall -o "%e" "%f"
excute : "./%e"
```

Comment: i have same problem have you figured it out or not??

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how old the post is, but here's a solution to the KDE compilation issue. I, too, was faced with this problem. I just went to the **Geany** website and checked the documentation for a solution.

To save you the trouble of searching, I am going to post the way to fix the problem here.

---

1. Go to Edit and click on Preferences.
2. Select the Tools tab and enter the following command in the field Terminal:

   ```
   urxvt -e sh -c
   ```

or

```
konsole -e sh -c
```

or (in case the above failed)

```
konsole --workdir . -e sh geany_run_script.sh
```

---

I tried this and it worked for me.

I really love the Geany IDE and didn't want to part with it, especially on KDE which I also favor.

Cheers.